# MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, mkannotationview

I use this code for create my custom annotation view.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    MKPinAnnotationView *pinAnnotation = nil;
    if(annotation != myMapView.userLocation) {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"myPin";
        pinAnnotation = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[myMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinAnnotation == nil )

            pinAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];

        pinAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;

        //instatiate a detail-disclosure button and set it to appear on right side of annotation
        UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [infoButton addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(showRestaurantDescription)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        pinAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;
    }    
    return pinAnnotation;
}
```

My problem is how to send parameter to my selector: -showRestaurantDescription:

As I think I can add tag to the button and handle it, but I need best way to choose, because I have array with my restaurants and when I tap on concrete pin I need to show current restaurant. So the tags in this case not very convenient as I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the delegate method `mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` to listen for taps on the button. That method gets passed an `annotationView` which has an `annotation` property. You can use the annotation property to figure out which restaurant it was.

Also, did you forget the colon in `action:@selector(showRestaurantDescription)`?